# AngularJS creating (and binding) form elements dynamically based on API response

Tags: json, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-service

I'm trying to create a member's form with all the pre-defined phone types.

[image: Contact Form]

I'm making two api requests for member and phone types. Here is what I've:

First request with member's information:

```
    $scope.member = {
    // $scope.member is returned from an api call
        "name": "John Doe",
        "phones": [{
            "id": "Cell",
            "phone": "(651) 111-1899",
            "phone_unlisted": false
        }, {
            "id": "Work",
            "phone": "(555) 121-1212",
            "phone_unlisted": true
        }]
    };
```

Second request to get phone types:

```
    myApp.controller("phoneTypes", function ($scope) {
        // $scope.phoneTypes is returned from an api call
        $scope.phoneNames = [{
            "id": "Cell"
        }, {
            "id": "Cell 2"
        }, {
            "id": "Work"
        }, {
            "id": "Work 2"
        }];
    });
```

An unsuccessful attempt to create this form.

HTML -

```
<div ng-controller="memberInfo">
    <h3>{{member.name}}</h3>
    <form role="form" ng-controller="phoneTypes">
        <h4>Phones</h4>
        <div ng-repeat="phoneName in phoneNames" >
            <label>{{phoneName.id}}</label>

            //need to bind phone detail from $scope.member if exists otherwise leave blank
            <input type="text" ng-model="member.phones.phone" />
            unlisted: <input type="checkbox" ng-model="member.phones.phone_unlisted" />
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

I need to bind phone number of each matched phone types, otherwise leave the input field blank.

Here is http://jsfiddle.net/4nzg4/

I've gone through various tutorials and posts but I'm not able to solve this. I'm new to AngularJS, any help will be appreciated.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach that doesn't immediately break bi-directional binding—but does have its own disadvantages—would be to add the missing phone types to `$scope.member` directly. This is a bit of a bigger modification to your existing code.

First, we need to combine both controllers and templates into a single template:

```
<div ng-controller="memberInfo">
    <h3>{{member.name}}</h3>
    <form role="form">
        <h4>Phones</h4>
        <div ng-repeat="phone in member.phones" >
            <label>{{phone.id}}</label>
            <input type="text" ng-model="phone.phone" />
            unlisted: <input type="checkbox" ng-model="phone.phone_unlisted" /> <br/>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Note that we are now `repeat`-ing through `member.phones` directly. But that doesn't have all the available phone types? Correct, but we'll fix that now.

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

myApp.controller("memberInfo", function ($scope) {

    // $scope.member is returned from an api call
    $scope.member = {
        "name": "John Doe",
        "phones": [{
            "id": "Cell",
            "phone": "(651) 111-1899",
            "phone_unlisted": false
        }, {
            "id": "Work",
            "phone": "(555) 121-1212",
            "phone_unlisted": true
        }]
    };
    var phoneNames = [{
        "id": "Cell"
    }, {
        "id": "Cell 2"
    }, {
        "id": "Work"
    }, {
        "id": "Work 2"
    }];

    // make an array of the phone id's in $scope.member.phones
    var currently_used_names = $scope.member.phones.map( function( phone ) {
        return phone.id;
    } ); // returns [ "Cell", "Work" ]

    // add any phone names that weren't listed
    phoneNames.forEach( function( name ) {
        if ( currently_used_names.indexOf( name.id ) === -1 ) {
            $scope.member.phones.push( {
                "id": name.id,
                "phone": "",
                "phone_unlisted": false
            } );
        }
    } );
});
```

In this case, we add to `$scope.member.phones` any of the phone types that need to be listed with some sort of default template.

**Advantage**: Keeps bi-directional binding.

**Disadvantage**: Adds "wrong" data to `$scope.member.phones`, though it is probably easy enough to filter out manually as necessary.

Here's [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dahjelle/C4Zmz/3/) to demonstrate.

Comment: Excellent! As always, thanks for the detailed response David. I tried to use angular.forEach to merge phone types to $scope.member but didn't have any luck. I need to remember to use "map" :)

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution—though I'm not comfortable it is the best—is to remap `phones` array into a `phones_object` where the key is the `id` of the phone. In other words, at the end of your `memberInfo` controller, you can:

```
$scope.member.phones_object = {};
$scope.member.phones.forEach( function( phone ) {
    $scope.member.phones_object[ phone.id ] = phone;
} );
```

Then, in the template, you use that object to display the phone numbers:

```
    <div ng-repeat="phoneName in phoneNames" >
        <label>{{phoneName.id}}</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="member.phones_object[ phoneName.id ].phone" />
        unlisted: <input type="checkbox" ng-model="member.phones_object[ phoneName.id ].phone_unlisted" /> <br/>
    </div>
```

That gives you what I [think is the result you want](http://jsfiddle.net/dahjelle/C4Zmz/1/).

[image: That gives you this result.]

Unfortunately, **this breaks Angular's bi-directional binding**, at least to the original `$scope.members.phones` data. You could use a `$watch` to keep the data in sync, if you wanted, or simply sync it back up when you are ready to re-submit data to the API, depending on your application.

Comment: Thanks David. This is exactly what I had in mind but I guess it does break bi-directional binding. At least I know what I was doing wrong :)